# C# input validation, first digit must be 1?

Tags: c#

I want to make sure my user input is 6 digits and start with digit 1. How can i make sure the input start with 1?

```
private static void GetCustomerInfo(out string accNumberC)
    {
        string accNumberC;

    Console.Write("Account number: ");
        accNumberC = Console.ReadLine();

    if (accNumberC == "" || accNumberC.Length < 6 || accNumberC.Length > 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
            accNumberC = null;
        }



    }
```

Comment: If you managed to use the `out` language construct, you should know how to do this input validation. Tip: Either `accNumberC[0] == '1'` or convert it to an `int` first to check if it's even a correct number.

Comment: The test of `""` is useless, since its length is not 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accNumberC) || accNumberC.Length != 6 || !accNumberC.StartsWith("1")) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the first character like with an index:

```
if (accNumberC == "" || accNumberC.Length != 6 || accNumberC[0] != '1') //or use StartsWith
{
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
        accNumberC = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `accNumberC[0]=='1'` comparison and flag the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse entered string into integer value:

```
int val;
if (!int.TryParse(accNumberC, out val))
{
    // string cannot be parsed as int.
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot parse entered value");
}
else if (val < 100000 || val > 199999)
{
    // value is not 6 digits length or doesn't start with 1.
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
}
else
{
    // acceptable value here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using regular expressions. Here's an example:

```
bool isValid(string accountNumber)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountNumber)) return false;

    var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(accountNumber,"^1\\d{5}$");
    return result.Success;
}
```